# React with Grunt and Babelify not working

Tags: reactjs, gruntjs, babeljs, browserify

I just started learning and developing using React in JSX. I want to use Grunt for building the files. I have the following folder structure:

```
Project root/
 |
 +-- src/
 |   |
 |   +-- js/
 |   +-- jsx/
 |
 +-- js/
```

Basically, I create my JSX files with my component classes inside of the `/src/jsx`folder. Then I want to transpile each individual file to a js file using *Babelify* with *Browserify*, which will land inside the `/src/js` folder. Then I want to bundle those files into a single file and minify that and put it into the `/js` folder using `UglifyJS`.

My `Gruntfile.js` looks like this:

```javascript
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n',
        compress: {
          keep_fnames: true
        },
        mangle: {
          keep_fnames: true
        }
      },
      build: {
        src: 'src/js/*.js',
        dest: 'js/build.min.js'
      }
    },
    browserify: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'src/jsx',
          src: ['*.jsx'],
          dest: 'src/js',
          ext: '.js'
        }],
        options: {
          transform: [['babelify', { presets: "react-app/prod" }]],
          browserifyOptions: {
            debug: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'browserify:dist',
    'uglify'
  ]);
};
```

But when I run `grunt` from the project directory and the load the page, I get the following error:

```
build.min.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: PageLayout is not defined
    at Object.1 (build.min.js:3)
    at o (build.min.js:3)
    at r (build.min.js:3)
    at build.min.js:3
```

My React classes look a little something like this:

```javascript
class PageLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <page-layout>
        <Navbar brandName="MyBrand" />
        <MainView />
      </page-layout>
    )
  }
}
```

(`Navbar` and `MainView` are components that are also defined in seperate JSX files)

I investigated and I found out that the files generated by Babelify inside the `/src/js` folder have those classes inside an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression). So the problem is that the classes are not globally accessible.

Now my question: **How can I fix this? Is there a better workflow with Grunt or another tool?** The tools don't really matter to me, as long as they run on Windows and can compile my files.

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor and look into parcel (https://parceljs.org/) or webpack (https://webpack.js.org/)

Comment: @SakoBu WebPack looks very promising. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: webpack is what create-react-app uses under the hood... (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)